# Recognize a user clicking a specific turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I have a model of the solar system. It creates 8 (sorry Pluto) turtle objects that orbit the Sun in a StepAll function that incrementally move each turtle at the same time on the screen. I want to add a function that allows for a user to click on a specific planet and for it to display specific information about the unique turtle that was clicked (display info about planets etc.)

Is this possible?

If not I have thought of buttons, but making them move along with the planets seems tricky... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [turtle.onclick(fun, btn=1, add=None)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#using-events)  - it assigns click event to every turtle individually.

Comment: BTW: turtle in background uses Tkinter which have more functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see if a mouse click is on a turtle in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348137/how-to-see-if-a-mouse-click-is-on-a-turtle-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just so happens that I've a [four inner planet simulator left over from answering another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083115/how-to-make-items-draw-at-the-same-time-in-python-using-turtle/40941423#40941423) that we can plug `onclick()` methods into to see how well this works with moving turtles:

```
""" Simulate motion of Mercury, Venus, Earth, and Mars """

from turtle import Turtle, Screen

planets = {
    'mercury': {'diameter': 0.383, 'orbit': 58, 'speed': 7.5, 'color': 'gray'},
    'venus': {'diameter': 0.949, 'orbit': 108, 'speed': 3, 'color': 'yellow'},
    'earth': {'diameter': 1.0, 'orbit': 150, 'speed': 2, 'color': 'blue'},
    'mars': {'diameter': 0.532, 'orbit': 228, 'speed': 1, 'color': 'red'},
}

def setup_planets(planets):
    for planet in planets:
        dictionary = planets[planet]
        turtle = Turtle(shape='circle')

        turtle.speed("fastest")  # speed controlled elsewhere, disable here
        turtle.shapesize(dictionary['diameter'])
        turtle.color(dictionary['color'])
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.sety(-dictionary['orbit'])
        turtle.pendown()

        dictionary['turtle'] = turtle

        turtle.onclick(lambda x, y, p=planet: on_click(p))

    revolve()

def on_click(planet):

    p = screen.textinput("Guess the Planet", "Which planet is this?")

    if p and planet == p:
        pass  # do something interesting

def revolve():

    for planet in planets:
        dictionary = planets[planet]
        dictionary['turtle'].circle(dictionary['orbit'], dictionary['speed'])

    screen.ontimer(revolve, 50)

screen = Screen()

setup_planets(planets)

screen.mainloop()
```

Generally, it works fine. Sometimes the planets stop in their orbits while the `textinput()` dialog panel is visible, other times they don't. I'll leave this issue for the OP to resolve, as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to every turtle individual function using [turtle.onclick()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.onclick)

```
import turtle

# --- functions ---

def on_click_1(x, y):
    print('Turtle 1 clicked:', x, y)

def on_click_2(x, y):
    print('Turtle 2 clicked:', x, y)

def on_click_screen(x, y):
    print('Screen clicked:', x, y)

# --- main ---

a = turtle.Turtle()
a.bk(100)
a.onclick(on_click_1)

b = turtle.Turtle()
b.fd(100)
b.onclick(on_click_2)

turtle.onscreenclick(on_click_screen)

turtle.mainloop()
```