# Running turtle multiple times but receiving a Terminator error after the first run

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I've made a 2D animation of the solar system by using turtle graphics and code from: [How to make items draw at the same time in python using turtle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083115/how-to-make-items-draw-at-the-same-time-in-python-using-turtle) by @cdlane

cdlane's code is:

```
""" Simulate motion of Mercury, Venus, Earth, and Mars """

planets = {
    'mercury': {'diameter': 0.383, 'orbit': 58, 'speed': 7.5, 'color': 'gray'},
    'venus': {'diameter': 0.949, 'orbit': 108, 'speed': 3, 'color': 'yellow'},
    'earth': {'diameter': 1.0, 'orbit': 150, 'speed': 2, 'color': 'blue'},
    'mars': {'diameter': 0.532, 'orbit': 228, 'speed': 1, 'color': 'red'},
}

def setup_planets(planets):
    for planet in planets:
        dictionary = planets[planet]
        turtle = Turtle(shape='circle')

        turtle.speed("fastest")  # speed controlled elsewhere, disable here
        turtle.shapesize(dictionary['diameter'])
        turtle.color(dictionary['color'])
        turtle.pu()
        turtle.sety(-dictionary['orbit'])
        turtle.pd()

        dictionary['turtle'] = turtle

    screen.ontimer(revolve, 50)

def revolve():
    for planet in planets:
        dictionary = planets[planet]
        dictionary['turtle'].circle(dictionary['orbit'], dictionary['speed'])

    screen.ontimer(revolve, 50)

screen = Screen()

setup_planets(planets)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Its important to note that this code works fine on the first run, however, when run more than once, I receive this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lach3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\lach3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 814, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\lach3\Desktop\Prog\from turtle import Turtle, Screen.py", line 31, in revolve
    dictionary['turtle'].circle(dictionary['orbit'], dictionary['speed'])
  File "C:\Users\lach3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 1998, in circle
    self.speed(speed)
  File "C:\Users\lach3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 2175, in speed
    self.pen(speed=speed)
  File "C:\Users\lach3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 2460, in pen
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\lach3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 2661, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "C:\Users\lach3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 2647, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "C:\Users\lach3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 1293, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

I've tried getting rid of screen.exitonclick() all together and replacing it with alternative exiting methods such as exiting with a key press or just having the animation close when the window is closed. Every method receives the same error...

How can I fix this?

Comment: The resolution to this issue depends on what environment you use to run the code.  E.g. at the shell command line (where it works fine), under a program development environment, like IDLE, etc.  Describe *your* environment.